# file upload using jquery ajax and asp.net handler

Tags: asp.net, jquery, file-upload, ashx

I am trying hard to get this working but i ma getting error while uploading file.

## ASPX

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" CssClass="file-upload-dialog" />
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnUpload" CssClass="btn upload" Text="Upload" />
```

## Handler

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
      {
            context.Response.ContentType = "multipart/form-data";
            context.Response.Expires = -1;
            try
            {
                  HttpPostedFile postedFile = context.Request.Files["file"];
                  string savepath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/assets/common/CompetitionEntryImages/");
                  var extension = Path.GetExtension(postedFile.FileName);

                  if (!Directory.Exists(savepath))
                        Directory.CreateDirectory(savepath);

                  var id = Guid.NewGuid() + extension;
                  if (extension != null)
                  {
                        var fileLocation = string.Format("{0}/{1}",
                                                         savepath,
                                                         id);

                        postedFile.SaveAs(fileLocation);
                        context.Response.Write(fileLocation);
                        context.Response.StatusCode = 200;
                  }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                  context.Response.Write("Error: " + ex.Message);
            }
      }
```

## Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            email = $("input[id$='emailHV']").val();
            alert(email);
            $('#aspnetForm').attr("enctype", "multipart/form-data");
      });



$('#<%= btnUpload.ClientID %>').on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var fileInput = $('#ctl00_PageContent_Signup_ctl06_MWFileUpload_FileUpload1');
            var fd = new window.FormData();
            fd.append('file', fileInput.files[0]);

            $.ajax({
                  url: '/charity-challenge/MWFileUploadHandler.ashx',
                  data: fd,
                  processData: false,
                  contentType: false,
                  type: 'POST',
                  success: function (data) {
                        alert(data);
                  }
            });
      });
```

## Error

[image]

## HTML

```
<input type="file" name="ctl00$PageContent$Signup$ctl06$MWFileUpload$FileUpload1" id="ctl00_PageContent_Signup_ctl06_MWFileUpload_FileUpload1" class="file-upload-dialog">

 <input type="submit" name="ctl00$PageContent$Signup$ctl06$MWFileUpload$btnUpload" 
value="Upload" onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new 
WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$PageContent$Signup$ctl06$MWFileUpload$btnUpload&quot;, 
&quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" 
id="ctl00_PageContent_Signup_ctl06_MWFileUpload_btnUpload" class="button">
```

## EDITS

Finally, i got it working by doing these things to form data

```
var fileData = fileInput.prop("files")[0];   // Getting the properties of file from file field
        var formData = new window.FormData();                  // Creating object of FormData class
        formData.append("file", fileData); // Appending parameter named file with properties of file_field to form_data
        formData.append("user_email", email);
```

## FULL WORKING CODE

```
$('#<%= btnUpload.ClientID %>').on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var fileInput = $('#<%= FileUpload1.ClientID %>');
            var fileData = fileInput.prop("files")[0];   // Getting the properties of file from file field
            var formData = new window.FormData();                  // Creating object of FormData class
            formData.append("file", fileData); // Appending parameter named file with properties of file_field to form_data
            formData.append("user_email", email);
            $.ajax({
                  url: '/charity-challenge/MWFileUploadHandler.ashx',
                  data: formData,
                  processData: false,
                  contentType: false,
                  type: 'POST',
                  success: function (data) {
                        var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
                        if (obj.StatusCode == "OK") {
                              $('#<%= imagePath.ClientID %>').val(obj.ImageUploadPath);
                              $('.result-message').html(obj.Message).show();
                        } else if (obj.StatusCode == "ERROR") {
                              $('.result-message').html(obj.Message).show();
                        }
                  },
                  error: function (errorData) {
                        $('.result-message').html("there was a problem uploading the file.").show();
                  }
            });
      });
```

Comment: can you post the HTML generated by `<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" CssClass="file-upload-dialog" />`. Also, in the console tab, you can type `var fileInput = $("#file-upload")` and check what value it has

Comment: it says undefined in the console.. i dont know why

Comment: yeah ! you are looking for an element with an id `file-upload`. There is no element with this id on the generated html. Try DaveHogan tip.

Comment: tried with the solution with no luck... still same error

Comment: well done on the details!

Answer (score 2):

After a whole afternoon of banging, I came back to this question/solution when I realized that you had specified "handler" rather than "service"  big difference.  :)  Also for a working hander that can run this jquery in the back I went to https://github.com/superquinho/jQuery-File-Upload-ASPnet and trimmed out what I didn't need.  Here is the handler code that I am using (VS2012).  As you can see I only use it right now for csv uploads.

```
Imports System
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Data

Public Class FileUpload : Implements IHttpHandler, IReadOnlySessionState
    Public Sub ProcessRequest(ByVal context As HttpContext) Implements IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest
        Try
            Select Case context.Request.HttpMethod
                Case "POST"
                    Uploadfile(context)
                    Return

            Case Else
                context.Response.ClearHeaders()
                context.Response.StatusCode = 405
                Return
        End Select

    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw
    End Try

End Sub

Private Sub Uploadfile(ByVal context As HttpContext)

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim files As String()
    Dim savedFileName As String = String.Empty
    Dim js As New Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer

    Try

        If context.Request.Files.Count >= 1 Then

            Dim maximumFileSize As Integer = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("UploadFilesMaximumFileSize")

            context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain"
            For i = 0 To context.Request.Files.Count - 1
                Dim hpf As HttpPostedFile
                Dim FileName As String
                hpf = context.Request.Files.Item(i)

                If HttpContext.Current.Request.Browser.Browser.ToUpper = "IE" Then
                    files = hpf.FileName.Split(CChar("\\"))
                    FileName = files(files.Length - 1)
                Else
                    FileName = hpf.FileName
                End If


                If hpf.ContentLength >= 0 And (hpf.ContentLength <= maximumFileSize * 1000 Or maximumFileSize = 0) Then
                    Dim d As Date = Now
                    savedFileName = HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath & "CSVLoad\" + d.Year.ToString + d.DayOfYear.ToString + d.Hour.ToString + d.Minute.ToString + d.Second.ToString + d.Millisecond.ToString + ".csv"

                    hpf.SaveAs(savedFileName)

                Else

                End If
            Next

        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw
    End Try

End Sub

Public ReadOnly Property IsReusable() As Boolean Implements IHttpHandler.IsReusable
    Get
        Return False
    End Get
End Property

End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#file-upload")
```

should be

```
$("#ctl00_PageContent_Signup_ctl06_MWFileUpload_file-Upload")
```

Look at changing the file-upload control on the server code to have a static server side id by using the `ClientIdMode` property. Like so:

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" CssClass="file-upload-dialog" ClientIdMode="Static" />
```

Then you can be sure the ID of the control in the client code will be `FileUpload1`

Comment: tried with the id generated in html by coping in jquery.. still no luck.. same error

Comment: Well the trick is to use the ClientIDMode to be static so you can ensure the elements client ID matches. (same with the button control).

Comment: yeah that's true but i am not able to do that cause it might cause some another issue. BUT i am putting the same id in jquery then why i am getting the error?

Comment: Ensure the ID's are definitely matching and confirm the result of `var fileInput` in your browsers watch / console window. If the ID exists then you will not get an 'undefined'.

Comment: see my edits please...i got it working by appending the filedata to form object

Answer (score 1):

use this in your web configuration file

```
<system.webServer>
 <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
<handlers>
    <add name="AjaxFileUploadHandler" verb="*" 
      path="AjaxFileUploadHandler.axd"
      type="AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadHandler, 
      AjaxControlToolkit"/>
</handlers>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
$("#<% = FileUpload1.clientID %>")
```