# File not reaching till handler's method

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload, c#-3.0, handler

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
            $("#Button1").click(function (evt) {
                var fileUpload = $('[id$=FileUpload1]')[0].value.split(",");

                      var data = new FormData();
                     for (var i = 0; i < fileUpload.length; i++) {
                          data.append(fileUpload[i].name, fileUpload[i]);
                        }

    var options = {};
    options.url = "Handler.ashx";
    options.type = "POST";
    options.data = data;
    options.contentType = false;
    options.processData = false;
    options.success = function (result) { alert(result); };
    options.error = function (err) { alert(err.statusText); };

   $.ajax(options);

   evt.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

This was my jquery and below is my handler file code ......

till end i am getting value while debugging but in motto of making upload multiple images at a while i am unable to have any value in handle

handler code

```java
public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {

        string filePath = "FileSave//";

        foreach (string file in context.Request.Files)
        {
            HttpPostedFile filed = context.Request.Files[file];
            filed.SaveAs(context.Server.MapPath(filePath  + filed.FileName));
            context.Response.Write("File uploaded");
        }
  }
```

Comment: Did you include your `document.ready` within `<script></script>` if at all it is placed in html

Comment: yes i did that .....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this way if you would like to.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $("#Button1").click(function (evt) {
          evt.preventDefault();
          var formdata = new FormData();
          var fileInput = $('#sliderFile'); //#sliderFile is the id of your file upload control
          if ($(fileInput).get(0).files.length == 0)
          { //show error
               return false;
          }
          else
          {
              $.each($(fileInput).get(0).files, function (index,value) {
                   formdata.append(value.name, value);
              });
              $.ajax({
                    url: 'Handler.ashx',
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: data,
                    processData: false,
                    contentType:false,
                    success: function (data) {
                            if (data.result) {
                                 //return true or any thing you want to do here
                            }
                            else {
                                 //return false and display error
                            }
                    },
                    error: function (data) {
                          //return false and display error
                    }
              });
          }
     });//button click close
 });//document.ready close
```

**Try it and let me know**

**EDIT**: Remember but, HTML5 FormData is not available in older browsers and your code will silently fail. If you need to support older browsers you might need to perform progressive enhancement by testing the capabilities of the browser and falling back to a standard form POST if the browser doesn't support `FormData`:

```
if(window.FormData === undefined) {
        // The browser doesn't support uploading files with AJAX
        // falling back to standard form upload
} else {
        // The browser supports uploading files with AJAX =>
        // we prevent the default form POST and use AJAX instead
        e.preventDefault();

        ...
}
```

For more information on this you can see answer I have accepted for one of my questions. It's pretty much clear there what is the issue regarding. [**Here is the link**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28917058/file-upload-through-ajax-does-not-append-file-in-request-in-mvc)

**EDIT : Just adding these [LINK1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17109357/file-upload-using-jquery-ajax-and-asp-net-handler) and [LINK2](http://www.chrisweldon.net/blog/2012/04/13/jquery-file-uploader/) for those who come looking for the answer.**

Comment: No no ..... still its not workable .... by debugging i came to know that my code runs perfactly but only problem is in handler no file is fatched after request

Comment: nop nop ..... i need to ask a thing ...... at your link code the controller part of your code ..... where should i write that ..... in which file .... ???

Comment: [HttpPost]    .....--->> to do write this santense is nt allowing ..... i  AM very NEW IN .NET  and confused

Comment: I just saw you are calling handler method. So what you can try is Just give the fully qualified path in the ajax url like **/PathToHandler/Handler.ashx**.
-
**EDIT** Please visit this **[Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24076309/in-mvc-how-to-call-ashx-handler-file-through-jquery)**

Comment: bro my handler file is giving context.Request.Files.Count == 0 .... always .... no data is going there so no uploading happenuing

Comment: Ok bro. I really don't have any experience with handler but still thought of getting some links for you so that you can work on.. **[This link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17109357/file-upload-using-jquery-ajax-and-asp-net-handler)** and **[This link](http://www.chrisweldon.net/blog/2012/04/13/jquery-file-uploader/)** might be helpful.

Comment: ohhn man finally m done with this task ..... thank you so much brotha ...... finally that links worked .......

Answer (score 1):

use `HttpContextBase[]` instead of just `HttpContext`